# How to execute CSSO command line CSS minifier on node.js

Tags: windows, node.js, command-line

I'm trying to use CSSO command line on **node.js**.

Sadly, I can't understand how to just be able of call `csso` command.

Check this page for CSSO's documentation: https://github.com/css/csso#33-from-the-command-line

I've followed documentation page's steps downloading CSSO using NPM. And it's already installed because I can do a `require("csso").justDoIt(".....")`, but this isn't fine for me, because I need to execute it in a command line since I require this CSS minifier during some Visual Studio build process.

---

**Note that a solution wouldn't be *use other compressor*, because I've tried YUI, AjaxMin and other ones having command line interfaces, and those don't merge duplicated classes, identifiers and selectors into a single one.**

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The csso file in the bin folder basically just calls the /csso/lib/csso.js file, so you should be able to patch your requirements around something like;

node /path/to/csso/lib/csso.js -i  -o

Untested, it may require some working of variables but that should get you started on a solution!

Answer (score 0):

use node's [child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
csso  = spawn('csso/bin/csso', ['test.css']);

csso.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but this isn't the command-line interface for CSSO. Double-check the link again  https://github.com/css/csso#33-from-the-command-line

Comment: When you install csso using npm, it will be installed in node_modules directory. You can then use csso binary path in the spawn call. In my case the csso binary is in <pwd>/node_modules/csso/bin/

Comment: May be I misunderstood your requirement. What exactly are you trying to achieve through node.js?

Comment: **[...] I require this CSS minifier during some Visual Studio build process.**. I'm in Windows (Windows Server 2008 R2).